# Base64 binary data type in java

Tags: java

I need to attach a Base64 binary element to a SOAP message...Im doing a dry run to check if I can convert a value read from a file into Base64 binary..

Here is the below code..In the last line I try to print the type of encoded1(I assume it should be Base64 binary values) but I get the following display..."Attachment[B"...How can I confirm if its Base64 binary string?

```
Path path = Paths.get("c:/tomcatupload/text.csv");
byte[] attachment1 = Files.readAllBytes(path);
byte[] encoded1 = Base64.encode(attachment1);
System.out.println("Attachment"+ encoded1.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: `[B` just means that it is a `byte` array

Comment: If you look online there are several online Base64 decoders.  Just copy/paste your Base64 data into the page and it will show you the corresponding "real" data.

Comment: If you used `Base64.encode` the result will be Base64 encoded.

Comment: If you convert an array of bytes into a Base64-encoded array of bytes, all you have is another array of bytes, it doesn't hold any "Base64 type" inherently.

Comment: are you saying you don't trust `java.util.Base64`? :)

Comment: You could write unit tests to actually validate the encoding, but this have probably been done by the developers/testers of `java.util.base64` ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Base-64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a way to convert arbitrary bytes to bytes that fit in a range of text characters in ASCII encoding. This is done without any interpretation whatsoever - raw bytes are converted to base-64 on sender's end; the receiver converts them back to a stream of bytes, and that's all there is to it.

When your code prints `encoded1.getClass().getName()`, all it gets is the static type of the byte array. In order to interpret the data encoded in base-64 as something meaningful to your program, you need to know the format of underlying data transported as base-64. Once the bytes are delivered to you (in your case, that's `encoded1` array of bytes) you need to decide what's inside, and act accordingly.

For example, if a serialized Java object is sent to you as base-64, you need to take `encoded1`, make an in-memory stream from it, and read the object using the regular serialization mechanism:

```
ByteArrayInputStream memStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(encoded1);
ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(memStream);
Object attachedObject = objStream.readObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

The encoding by Base64.encode() was successful if and only if **size** of encoded1  **>** size of obtained attachment1.

Please refer, to understand how the encoding works.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

By the way, your last statement doesn't print the array content. It prints the name of the class to which  encoded1 belongs to.

Comment: I would change your sentence to "The encoding **by Base64.encode()** was successful if and only if *size of encoded1* > *size of attachment1*", because on its own, greater length does not mean base64-encoded :P But I'm being picky here ^^